# Converting a excel field from a % to a decimal in a new formula

Tags: excel, formula

I have 4 different values being generated on a spreadsheet in different cells:

```
A=88.45%
B=88.45%
C=1.69%
D=95.67%
```

I need to add these values up and divide it by 4 to get the difference from a possibility of 100%. So, the functions I've written are:

```
A= =SUM(1-(D6/C6))
B= =SUM(1-(F6/C6))
C= =SUM(I6/H6)
D= =SUM(1-(K6/C6))
```

However, if I just have a formula that adds those cells up while they are displaying as a % and then divide it by 4 it doesn't give me the intended number which I need. The only way I've figured out to give me the accurate result was to convert them into decimals, but I'm not sure how to exactly write that. If it's even possible. I still need them displaying as a % in the original cells is the issue.

```
A= 0.1155
B= 0.1155
C= 0.0169
D= 0.0433
```

Divide those by 4 and you get the correct 7.28%. Then I need to subtract that from 100% to generate the actual average of those 4 cells.

Any insight?

Comment: A value displayed as a percent, and the same value displayed as a decimal, are exactly the same in Excel. You are missing something in what you are observing, or describing.

Comment: So, this is wrong then? =SUM(1-E34)+(1-G34)+(J34)+(1-L34)/4

That is taking the deficit of A, B, and D and adding all 4 together, dividing by 4. That returns 25.88% where as if they are added by decimal then it returns 7.28%.

Comment: I can't see your screen, so I really have no way of knowing the contents of `E34`, `G34`, `J34` or `L34`.  But I would ask why you are treating `J34` differently?

Comment: E34 is A, G34 is B, J34 is C, L34 is D. J34 is treated differently because it is dividing information from 2 different cells and I'm not in need of the deficit for the average.

Comment: Above you have different values for A.  First you have `A=88.45%`, and lower down you show `A=0.1155`.  Same with B, C, and D.  Hard to know what you are doing.

Comment: It would be simple to figure out his issue if he would present his data clearly. But I think he got distracted thinking about percent vs decimal, for some reason.

Comment: NAME 277 32 88.45% 32 88.45% 12357 209 1.69% 12 95.67%

I hope this translates well. So, A= 88.45%, B=88.45%, C=1.69%, D=95.67%. So, I need to add those 4 up and divide by 4, which should return 7.28% or 100%-7.28%=92.72% but the above formula doesn't work. It however does work if I add them as decimals.

Comment: @Josh Adding percent's and adding the equivalent decimals, in Excel, gives exactly the same mathematical results. The only difference is the cell format. If you are getting different results, you are not performing the same operation on the same data.  Suggest you upload an xlsx file that demonstrates the problem, to some sharing site, and post a link here if you need further advice.

Comment: Ok, take a look: https://i.imgur.com/4FUaLEA.jpg

Comment: That is not an xlsx file. Your screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet and does not show the formulas you are having a problem with. To make the data useful upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zWzZ5UT7T-IuU8GuAZ2UyhV6QJfW9zbJv-LiLbihXLA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as **Completely** unclear what you're asking *Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.* It wasn't clear when you posted it ant is even more obfuscated now.

Comment: Fairly simple. I'm trying to get 7.28% as the result from dividing the 4 cells. However, I'm unable to do this by using the values as a % as you can see.

If I add them all together as a decimal and divide it by 4 I get the intended result. Otherwise, I receive a completely different result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT* 2nd formula added

The proper formula to obtain your desired result of 7.28% from the four values in Row 34 (January) is:

```
=SUM(1-E34,1-G34,J34,1-L34)/4
```

OR

```
=1-AVERAGE(E34,G34,1-J34,L34)
```

where:

```
E34:= 88.45%
G34:= 88.45%
J34:=  1.69%
L34:= 95.67%
```

As an aside, the `SUM` function in each of those cells is entirely superfluous.

```
=1-D34/C34
```

will give the same result as

```
=SUM(1-(D34/C34))
```

Comment: Appreciate it. In that line how do I have it take 7.28% minus 100%? -1 produces the result, but as a negative. Am I placing it in the wrong position?

Comment: 7.28% - 100% will always be a negative number since 100 is greater than 7.28

Comment: Right, so then how do we make it display 92.72%?

Comment: Uh, subtract the smaller number from the larger number?  Or maybe just take the AVERAGE of the values:  `=AVERAGE(E34,G34,1-J34,L34)` which will give the same result in a less convoluted fashion.

Comment: Appreciate your help.